# Is continuum $ 2^{\mathbb{R}}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I had questions if exist A $\neq \emptyset $ that |A|=|P(A)|

And my doubt is if $ |2^{\mathbb{R}}|=|\mathbb{R}|$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem

Comment: For any set $A$, the cardinality of $2^A$ is greater than the cardinality of $A$.

Answer (score 3):

The cardinality of the powerset $P(A)$, which is $|2^A|$,  is *always* strictly greater than the cardinality of $A.$

$$\;|A| \lt |P(A| = \left|2^{A}\right|$$

So it follows that $|\mathbb R| \lt \left|2^{\mathbb R}\right|$.

What *is* true is that $|\mathbb R| = \left|2^{\mathbb Z}\right|.$